# Usage of catch_backtrace

Tags: julia

Recently, I found that `catch_backtrace` only works when it is called immediately after `catch`. Is it the intended behaviour? Am I using the `backtrace` correctly?

```rb
try
    div(1,0)
catch e
    bt = catch_backtrace()
    showerror(STDOUT, e, bt)
end

DivideError: integer division error
 in div at ./int.jl:79
 in include_string at loading.jl:266
 in execute_request_0x535c5df2 at /usr/local/share/julia/site/v0.4/IJulia/src/execute_request.jl:177
 in eventloop at /usr/local/share/julia/site/v0.4/IJulia/src/IJulia.jl:141
 in anonymous at task.jl:447

try
    div(1,0)
catch e
    println(3)
    bt = catch_backtrace()
    showerror(STDOUT, e, bt)
end

3
DivideError: integer division error
```

Comment: I think it would be better to print those traces to `STDERR` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be isolated to IJulia. I can't reproduce on the REPL, and I have used `catch_backtrace()` several times (after other calls) in scripts.